# Does Oracle SQL Loader know anything about multilevel CVS?

Tags: sql-loader, multi-level

I want to populate a table with records from a multilevel CSV. The first line is more like a summary of the rows that come after - it is representing some averages and other numbers that are generated based on the data below it.
So, basically, the fact that it has a header row (with summary data not the column header) and an extra first column (which indicates the level of the record) is the only thing that makes it a multilevel CSV.

It looks something like this:

```
**1** | avg1 | avg2 | avg3
**2** | abc1 | abc2 | abc3 | abc4 | abc5 | abc6 | abc7 | abc8
**2** | abc1 | abc2 | abc3 | abc4 | abc5 | abc6 | abc7 | abc8
**2** | abc1 | abc2 | abc3 | abc4 | abc5 | abc6 | abc7 | abc8
```

I really need only the effective data, not the summary row, so I can ignore the first row and column and let the import process the rest. Supposedly I would need to save also the header part in future - most like in other table with some relations to the first one (and I know the above example is not very expressly) - I was wondering if SQL loader does already know how to process multilevel CSVs.

Comment: Please show actual data. Maybe highlight what you need to load.  If you have any control over this, just load it all because it's a matter of time before that header data will be needed, then you'll be the hero because it's already there.